# Extract a 2d matrix from 4d matrix JS

Tags: javascript, opencv, matrix, electron

I'm using electron with openCV with [opencv4nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs). My goal is to do the [Deep Learning based Human Pose Estimation using OpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-human-pose-estimation-using-opencv-cpp-python/) tutorial in JS instead of Python.

I'm quite new to JS but I'm very familiar with Python and I know that if I want to extract a 2d array from a 4d array (like in stage 3.4 line 7 in the python code), I can do `myArray[0, 0, :, :]`. Is there a similar functionality in JS openCV build for matrix objects?

I have tried to use the `at` function of the matrix object but it returns the first element of the 2d submatrix, e.g. `myArray.at(0,0)` is equal to `myArray.at(0,0,0,0)`. So it did not work.

If you know a solution with a normal JS array it's also good since I can [convert between a matrix and array](https://answers.opencv.org/question/84203/convert-mat-image-into-2d-matrix-double/).

I could probably copy the submatrix element wise but it will be inefficient (and I don't know how to). If there is a function that could copy a matrix from a smaller dimension I would like to know. But the optimal solution would be to get a shallow copy of the submatrix.

Thanks in advance.